# libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined symbol: cuDevicePrimaryCtxGetState

Tags: tensorflow

I have installed tensorflow-gpu with conda successfully. When I test doing import tensorflow I have the issue mentioned above. Any idea? I have checked my drivers, the nvidia toolkit and cudnn are intalled correctly and set the values of PATH, LD_LIBRARY_PATH and CUDA_HOME respectively.
...Fri Nov 23 12:00:18 2018
+------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.107    Driver Version: 340.107        |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro FX 5600      Off  | 0000:02:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 61%   77C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      2MiB /  1535MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Compute processes:                                               GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Process name                                     Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0            Not Supported                                               |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the proper minimum CUDA support (seems like it's 7 https://askubuntu.com/questions/988787/nvidia-cuda-theano-could-not-find-symbol-cudeviceprimaryctxgetstate) with cuDNN 3.

Upgrade your drivers if possible to get this version.

Otherwise, use either `tensorflow-mkl` or for older CPU models `tensorflow-eigen`.

Comment: thanks! but  are tensorflow-mkl or tensorflow-eigen GPU ? I do really need to try with GPU. I am using cuDNN 7, CUDA 9.2 and my card is Quadro FX 5600   with driver updated to Driver Version: 340.107. CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5420  @ 2.50GHz

Comment: No, they are not. But what the error message means is that it cannot find the latest install of the Cuda libraries.

Comment: Check the LD_LIBRARY_PATH variable and make sure the path to Cuda libraries is there.

Comment: Thanks! checked that, don't know what I am missing export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-9.0/bin:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/lib64:$PATH

Comment: Do you mean cuda toolkit? or cudnn or cupti?? Thanks!

Comment: Cuda toolkit to start with, cudnn should also be in your path.

Comment: Both are. However I am installing tensorflow-gpu with conda and using virtual env. I can see conda also install the toolkit and cudnn ...

Comment: Oh... That may be the reason. Check the library path to see if you can use your own. Although conda should have installed compatible ones though. You should play with both libraries (your own and conda's) to see which ones to use properly.

Comment: /anaconda3/envs/tf_gpu_1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/../libtensorflow_framework.so: undefined symbol: cuDevicePrimaryCtxGetState

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - I had already installed the required NVIDIA drivers on my Ubuntu machine, but when I tried to import Tensorflow I got the same error.

So for me the problem was that I was using the Nouveau driver instead of the NVIDIA driver.  In order to fix the issue you need to go to `System Settings`->`Software & Updates`->`Additional Drivers` and select the option `Using NVIDIA binary driver ...` and then click at the `Apply Changes` button. Then just reboot and you're done.